# How to store multiple values in a variable during run time(dynamically) in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I am trying to store multiple folder names in a variable during run time, because I want to access all these folders with their names later on.

This is what I have thus far:

[image: Task screenshot]

Comment: Show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please find attached pic for your reference.

Comment: Please don not attach pics of the code snippets. Rather than doing that post your code here so we can actually play with it

Comment: I am sorry Automation Anywhere doesn't allow pasting outside of the tool. So I can only attach the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no graceful way to do this with a `List` variable. You could solve this in a multitude of ways though! To my best knowledge, I would go about it by creating a Array. This way we can access the folder names later without having to do any additional tricks.

I started writing this out in text but realized a simple snippet would speak a thousand:

[image]

I opened line 5 on the right, to illustrate the reinitialize command.

On line 9 you can see I can select any folder name from the array at will. Just make sure you do not enter a number greater than `vFolderCount`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roel for your kind help. This was really very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer formally if this was indeed the solution to your proposed question.